# Wave like screen flicker at 60hz but not 40hz?

Tags: display, sony-vaio

I just picked up a Sony Vaio duo yesterday. However, I have found that it probably has a defective screen.

It is a 1080p IPS LCD, but the issue is, when I display solid colors, I can see noticeable wave like screen flickering, like what you would see if you were shaking an LCD or rapidly softly tapping an LCD. However, when I change the refresh rate to 40hz (the only other option besides 60), the flickering noticeably disappears.

I'm probably taking the unit back, but does anyone have a possible cause any ideas on why this happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first hand experience with this, but I wonder if the flickering relates to the refresh being at the same rate as your lights causing a noticeable affect.  (I've noticed something similar with some 3d TV's in the store).  One solution might be to see what happens with the lights off ?

That said, its probably the LCD - and as its a Sony you should replace it for a different brand.